# my function gives me these errors: "expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'double'" and "unknown type name 'skater_t"

Tags: c

This is my code and it gives me these errors:
"expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'double'"  and
"unknown type name 'skater_t".

What should I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct skater_t  {
    char name[20],surname[20];
    double referee[6][1];
    double average;
    }


double calculateAverageScore(const skater_t *skater);


int main()
{

   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a semicolon after structure declaration.

```
struct skater_t  {
    char name[20],surname[20];
    double referee[6][1];
    double average;
    }; /* <- add ; here */
```

Then, you should mark it as structure when you use structure type.

```
/* add "struct" befure "skater_t" */
double calculateAverageScore(const struct skater_t *skater);
```